# Using D3-Lasso in Angular 6

Tags: typescript, d3.js, angular6, d3.js-lasso

I am using D3.Js and lasso in my Angular 6 project. I have initialized lasso with `start()`, `draw()` and `stop()` functions. But I don't know how to bind this lasso with my svg. In traditional JavaScript, they use following syntax.

```
svg.call(lasso_object);
```

How do I do this in Angular? Here is my code in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wwmr42?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: if you add a stackblitz with a minimal example which replicates your issues, you'll have a better chance of more hlep

Comment: I have updated my code in stackblitz. Appreciate your help.

Comment: on stackblitz, error is "Cannot find module 'd3-lasso'"... do you get the same in your local env?

Comment: It's not the problem in the local env. I have installed d3-lasso using npm.

Comment: Hey! did you manage to make it work ? I'm asking because I'm dealing with the same issue here.

Comment: J.Doe , I did not. I had to finally make a lasso tool from scratch
  1. Drawing free shapes on the page making top left coordinate (0,0)
  2. Identifying if we create a closed object
  3. Creating a selection if the object is closed, otherwise initialize ability to draw again
  4. Identify objects inside the selected area and make them selected ( change their border color )
  5. get the names of objects inside for the process you need
  6. (and of course make the line of selection to a dotted line to make it more select-y)